# Is there a way to handle fields with only spaces using ODI?

Tags: xsd, oracle-data-integrator, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have a json file with the following snippet

```
{
    "brandName": "b1Name",
    "brandDesc": "b1Desc",
    "brandId": "75",
    "storeName": " "
},
{
    "brandName": "b2Name",
    "brandDesc": "b2Desc",       
    "brandId": "81",
    "storeName": null
},
```

And for mapping purposes, the following XSD file is created

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/BrandListReference_getBrands_response"
            targetNamespace="http://TargetNamespace.com/BrandListReference_getBrands_response"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/nxsd" nxsd:version="JSON"
            nxsd:jsonTopLevelArray="true" nxsd:encoding="UTF-8">
  <xsd:element name="brands">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="brand" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="brandName" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="brandDesc" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="brandId" type="xsd:integer"/>
              <xsd:element name="storeName" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:annotation xmlns="">
    <xsd:appinfo>NXSDSAMPLE=</xsd:appinfo>
    <xsd:appinfo>USEHEADER=false</xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:schema>
```

Translation Failure.
Failed to translate JSON to XML. cannot normalize!
The incoming data does not conform to the NXSD schema. Please correct the problem.

After checking the JSON and nulling storeName in the first element transformation works fine.
Is there a way to handle spaces only string values? As I have no control over the data provided in the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Befor insert to target table in Mapping(Interface), you use Component Split to split data to 2 target.
If trim(col) is null data go to error_table
If trim(col) is not null data go to target_table

Comment: The part I'm trying to figure out is how the XSD could handle this, is there a special attribute or way to define the element to handle only space fields?